# active class not being updated as expected with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So here is my Route Definition:

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: HomeRoute(store),
  childRoutes: [
    {
      onEnter: verifyAuthentication(store),
      component: redirectOnAuthenticationLost(),
      childRoutes: [
        // Authenticated Routes
        CounterRoute(store)
      ]
    },
    {
      childRoutes: [
        // Open Routes
        GameRoute(store),
        {
          ...Login,
          onEnter: redirectAuthentication(store)
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

And here is my Menu Component, which is in CoreLayout.

```
export const Menu = (props) => (
  <menu className={classes.menu}>
    <ul className={classes.menuList}>
      <li className={classes.menuItem}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="active" to="/">Terra<strong>Strike</strong></IndexLink>
      </li>
      <li className={classes.menuItem}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="active" to="/game">Game</IndexLink>
      </li>
      <li className={classes.menuItem}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="active" to="/counter">Counter</IndexLink>
      </li>
      <li className={classes.menuItem} style={{display: props.isAuthenticated ? 'none' : 'inline-block'}}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="active" to="/login">Login</IndexLink>
      </li>
      <li style={{display: !props.isAuthenticated ? 'none' : 'inline-block'}} className={classes.menuItem}>
        <a href="#" onClick={props.logout}>Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
);
```

The navigation of the Menu works as expected, but the active class is only set initially and when the props `isAuthenticated` is changed. Any idea what I am doing wrong or is that a bug from the library?

The router is updating the store, as you can see here:

[image: store]

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your code. Generally speaking, you need to know which Redux action you're expecting to have change the active class. I'm guessing `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`. Then you need to check the reducers that handle that action, and make sure that they are pure functions. If you're not sure what that means, watch https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-pure-and-impure-functions

Post the code of the reducer that handles that action in this question, since it's needed to offer a solution.